# Get value from document.querySelector and insert into localhost database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to get the value from document.querySelector and save the data into the database via form with ajax and php, but the code I wrote did not run well / could not display the result, if there was an error in writing my code

```
<script>
//on the click of the submit button 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        //get the form value
        let no = document.querySelector('i[data-name="no"]').value;
        let question = document.querySelector('i[data-name="question"]').value;
        let countdown = document.querySelector('i[data-name="countdown"]').value;
        let answer = document.querySelector('i[data-name="answer"]').value;
        //make the postdata
        var postData = 'no=' + no + '&question=' + question + '&countdown=' + countdown + 
        '&answer=' + answer;
        if (no == '' || question == '' || countdown == '' || answer == '') {
            alert("Please Fill All Fields");
        } else {
            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "post-answer.php",
                data: postData,
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

this is the form I created

```
<form class="glass userform" method="post" data-ajax="false">
<i data-name='countdown'></i><i data-name='answer'></i>
<i data-name='no'></i>
<a href=""
    style="float:right;font-size: 30px;width: 50px;margin-right:50px;margin-top:30px;display: 
inline-block;"><i>Next</i></a>
<i data-name='question'></i>
<br>
<a href="#" onclick="checkboxtrue();"
    style="width:100%;text-align: center;font-size: 30px;display: inline-block;"><i>Benar
    </i></a><br>
<a href="#" onclick="checkboxfalse();"
    style="width:100%;text-align: center;font-size: 30px;display: inline-block;"><i>Salah</i></a> 
<br><br>
<input type="hidden" id="checkboxtotext" name="checkboxtotext" onkeyup="valueoftrueanswer()" />
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: In order to increase the chance someone will help you, you need to provide more details about the problem.  Saying "the code did not run well" is not helpful.  Please explain what you're expecting to occur and what actually happened.

Comment: @Tibrogargan when I run the code, the data is not stored in the database

Comment: `document.querySelector('i[data-name="no"]').value` - the elements you are accessing there are not input fields, they do not have a `value`. You should access their `innerText` or `textContent` instead.